# Does smbfs create constant inode numbers?

Tags: linux, unix, samba, nfs, inode

If I use smbfs to mount a filesystem, will the inodes always be the same for each file? Or am I in danger of the inodes changing when I mount the fs again or if the remote system reboots?

Answer (score 3):

No. smbfs like other non-posix filesystems use a memory cache to try to maintain a stable database of inodes for files. If that cache is flushed or filled, it will loose all information of what inode corresponds to a file. That means reboots, but also can happen without a reboot, for instance check the following discussion: http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-findutils@gnu.org/msg01212.html

Best of luck,
João Miguel Neves